# IOS Battery Capacity information

Tags: ios, xcode, battery, iokit, capacity

All IOS battery Apps that can be found on Appstore today have the same problem. They all show wrong "MaxCapacity" 
(the maximum capacity that the battery can hold today) 
(not the original capacity that the battery can hold when manufactured).

The problem is that the MaxCapacity is very "insensitive". 
It updates every 100mAh.

Example, if the capacity is 1767mAh, the MacCapacity will show 1700mAh and will keep showing that until it passes 1699mAh, then it will switch to 1600mAh.

There is an app for OSX named CoconutBattery. 
This program can show the right capacity.

Anyone who know what calls CoconutBattery are using to get this detailed info?

I have tried the project EEIOKitListener (which I believe use the IOKit)
and this example also show the same behavour as the apps on Appstore.

I need and IOS app that can show the right MaxCapacity information.

Comment: Asking for an app is offtopic for stackoverflow. stackoverflow is ment for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get maxCapacity by using [UIDeviceListener](https://github.com/eldade/UIDeviceListener)

Example:

```
BatteryData =     {
        BatterySerialNumber = REDACTED;
        ChemID = 355;
        CycleCount = 524;
        DesignCapacity = 1420;
        Flags = 640;
        FullAvailableCapacity = 1325;
        ManufactureDate = REDACTED;
        MaxCapacity = 1273;
        MfgData = REDACTED;
        QmaxCell0 = 1350;
        StateOfCharge = 100;
        Voltage = 4194;
    };
```

Data might be very limited for iOS 10.

Comment: Didnt get any useful information when using UIDeviceListener (with IOS 10).

Answer (score 0):

this is show only battery percent level.

in Objective-c

```
UIDevice *Device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
double batteryLvl = (float)[myDevice batteryLevel];
NSLog(@"batteryLvl : %f",batteryLvl);
```

Swift 3+ :

```
let Device = UIDevice.current
Device.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
let batteryLvl: Double = Double(Device.batteryLevel)
print("batteryLvl : \(batteryLvl)")
```

OutPut :-

batteryLvl : 0.650000